# Date constructors provide unexpected results when called with similar arguments

Tags: javascript, date

I got one weird issue with `Date` object initialization. And wondering if someone can explain why..

```
var exp1 = new Date('2014-10-17');
var exp2 = new Date(2014,9,17);
var exp3 = new Date('17 Oct 2014');
console.log(exp1);
console.log(exp2);
console.log(exp3);
```

Results:

```
 Thu Oct 16 2014 18:00:00 GMT-0600 (MDT) // 16th?
 Fri Oct 17 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (MST) // Why GMT -7
 Fri Oct 17 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (MDT) // The only one that works as expected
```

Why are these three `Date` objects so different?

Comment: Did you actually write in 9 for the second call? or is that a typo that should be 10?

Comment: @badaboom Which browser are you using?

Comment: @mdewitt Month value begins with 0: "Integer value representing the month, beginning with 0 for January to 11 for December". https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: @GergoErdosi Safari - Version 6.1.6 (7537.78.2) - Mac OS X 10.7.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first date is treated as GMT since no time zone offset is provided.  When logged out it shows the time in your local timezone.  Adding an offset (`exp4` below), I get the date expected.

```
var exp1 = new Date('2014-10-17');
var exp2 = new Date(2014,9,17);
var exp3 = new Date('17 Oct 2014');
var exp4 = new Date('2014-10-17z-0500');
```

Results:

```
Thu Oct 16 2014 19:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)
Fri Oct 17 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time) 
Fri Oct 17 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time) 
Fri Oct 17 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)
```

I am not sure about `exp2` for you, but suspect it has something to do with daylight savings time and that you live in an area that does not observe daylight savings (Arizona?).

Edit:  this seems to be browser specific.  The results above were generated in Chrome while in IE 11, `exp4` was an invalid date.  For IE 11 I had to use this format:

```
var exp4 = new Date('2014-10-17T00:00-05:00');
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer. Time zone offset.. may be you right. Didn't think about it. But anyway exp1 and exp3 confusing me. Why in first case is pointed to GMT but in second it works fine? Pretty unexpected functionality..

Comment: @badaboom Yes, the difference between exp1 and exp3 is unexpected.  I haven't seen anything in documentation to explain it, so at this point I believe it depends on the implementation in the browser and that they are handling the 2 strings differently when parsing.

Comment: ok, thank you. But I think is not related to browser implementation, may be something in JS.. tested in all latest browsers

Comment: @ adrift If you'll find anything in future, please type few words here